# Use SilentParameter with MSAL4J to acquire/save token in cache

Tags: java, azure-ad-msal, msal4j

I am trying to create test application where I can obtain access token for fhir server. I setup infra ready and tested and it works fine.

After, I am using MSAL4J to obtain access token. I first used `ClientCredentialParameter` and it works:

```
PublicClientApplication pca = PublicClientApplication.builder(clientId).
                authority(authority).
                build();
ClientCredentialParameters clientCredentialParameters = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(Collections.singleton(fhirUrl)).build();
IAuthenticationResult result = app.acquireToken(clientCredentialParameters).get();
String token = result.accessToken();
```

Here is the issue now. I want to not only obtain access token, but want tokens to be saved in cache and renewed using MSAL4J `SilentParameter`. Here is my code:

```
PublicClientApplication pca = PublicClientApplication.builder(clientId).
                authority(authority).
                build();
SilentParameters silentParameters = SilentParameters.builder(Collections.singleton(fhirUrl), account).build();
IAuthenticationResult result = pca.acquireTokenSilently(silentParameters).get();
String token = result.accessToken();
```

I am having trouble what this `account` needs to be. I found that `PublicClientApplication` has `getAccounts`, but how can I save it in the first try? Do I need to use other parameters object to save token in cache, then use `SilentParameters`? Is my approach not correct in the first place?